# MaterialApp doesn't rebuild after changing locale

Tags: flutter, localization, intl

`MaterialApp` isn't rebuilding after I change `locale`. It changes texts only after I use hot reload. I put `print` to see if the state of `LanguageBloc` rebuilds and it does.

I am using:
`intl: 0.18.1`
`Flutter 3.16.9`

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    final AppRouter _appRouter = dependencies.get();
    final ThemeBloc _themeBloc = dependencies.get();
    final LanguageBloc _languageBloc = dependencies.get();

    return BlocBuilder(
      bloc: _themeBloc,
      builder: (BuildContext context, ThemeState themeState) {
        return AppThemeWidget(
          theme: themeState.theme,
          child: BlocBuilder(
            bloc: _languageBloc,
            builder: (BuildContext context, LanguageState languageState) {
              print(languageState.currentLanguage.code);

              return MaterialApp.router(
                routerConfig: _appRouter.config(),
                locale: Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: languageState.currentLanguage.code),
                localizationsDelegates: const [
                  S.delegate,
                  GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
                ],
                supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,
                builder: BotToastInit(),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I tried returning whole `Locale` object from state, different `Locale` constructors and using `setState`. None of those worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `key` to your `MaterialApp` widget based on your current language in order to force the rebuild:

```dart
MaterialApp.router( 
  key: ValueKey(languageState.currentLanguage.code),
  routerConfig: _appRouter.config(),
  locale: Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: languageState.currentLanguage.code),
  ...
)
```